# Jenkins Groovy: Given SSH Private Key, how to get SSH Public Key and/or key signature?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I need to perform a check on the SSH Credentials in a Jenkins server against some of our accounts in GitHub.

Now, using the GitHub API, I can pull a list of pubkeys associated to an account.

Using `com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials` I can dump the credentials in the Jenkins server. For SSH Credentials, I only get the Private Key (and its password), but neither the Public Key nor Keysig is available.

Is there a way to get SSH Public Key and/or SSH Key Signature from the retrieved Private Key?

Answer (score 2):

Once you got the private keys from jenkins using the com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials, you can **generate the the public key** associated to each one using the next commands:

For example:

```
ssh-keygen -e -f private_key > private_key.pub
```

You can also identify the user in GitHub using the **private key** by executing:

```
ssh -i /path/to/private_key -T git@github.com
```

Cheers

Comment: What about the "key signature"? Where does that come from?